# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Verification Email Customisation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have set up a custom Password Reset policy in Azure AD B2C that allows the user to change their password while displaying custom branding elements depending on specific scenarios. This policy contains a step where the user verifies their Email Address by entering a verification code that is sent to their inbox.

From this post in the Microsoft Azure Feedback Forums: [fully-customizable-verification-emails](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails)

It seems it is not possible to fully customise verification emails.

However, is it possible to perform some basic customisation of the verification e-mail within a custom policy? (text sent in the "From" and "Title" sections of the email and modifications to the text sent in the body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you aren't able to customize the email messages, but -- as [you have found on the feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails) -- this is being considered by the product team.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the verification emails by using a 3rd party email service to send the emails.

For example, we have Azure AD B2C configured to send emails with SendGrid. We then use SendGrid templates to customise the contents of the email. This involves using Custom Policies, so it's definitely an advanced use case.

Once set up, you can create and use any SendGrid email template, and use the {{otp}} and {{email}} parameters in the body of the email, which will be replaced dynamically with the one-time password value and the user email address.

The instructions to send emails with SendGrid are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

For Mailjet, the instructions are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-mailjet?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: can i use totp in conjunction with custom email i am trying to integrate totp MFA with custom email but it redirects to page content not found page

Comment: @mominnaveed yes, you can. That's what we've got working. I would guess there's some issue in the custom policy. They're pretty hard to debug unfortunately.